# Android - Copy string from external URL - Is it possible?

Tags: php, android, jquery, html

I have an app that need to get a string from an external URL that i don't own. For example, i need the app find the expression between "point A" to "point B" in the text of the external html file and get the whole text between the 2 points.

I thought it was possible to be done by searching the text through the webview, but i read in another post that Android won't allow my app to copy the text found in webview and then paste into a textview.

So, is it impossible to do? I'm thinking about what would be a better way to do it then... can you suggest me something? Maybe with an html/asp file in my server to do that search and then i would get the strings through my "website search" tool.

I don't know if it is the best way and can't imagine how could i do that.

Thanks for any kind of suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can access the url from the WebView. So you can then make your own request to get the HTML and do the search.

Something like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

                connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isw);

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line).append('\n');
                }

                String html = builder.toString();
                Log.d("HTML", html);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I tried this code, but the app can't get the string... i put a toast.makeText message below "finally" and it keeps me showing this toast message... I tried to replace "r.readLine" for "br.readLine"... is there any other thing i might try?

Comment: I edited the answer fixing some code mistakes and wrapping the network call in a different thread. Now you should see the result in Log.d. Instead of Thread you should use some other class like AsyncTask to make the call. I used Thread to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL externalURL = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347333/android-
        copy-string-from-external-url-is-it-possible");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(externalURL.openStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response += inputLine + '\n';
}
in.close();
return response
```

Run this piece of code on some other thread instead of main (`AsyncTask` will do the job), do the parsing thing, apply `response` to your `TextView` and you have your external url reader.

Comment: Thaks for commenting! I tried to do that, but "readLine" is not working with AsyncTask... it says "error: illegal start of type". Is there any other thing i might try?

Comment: You have to put everything in try/catch with handling `MalformedURLException` and `IOException`. If you are running this code in AndroidStudio,  `alt + enter` and add catch clause.

Comment: And for that illegal start, check your braces. And make sure that your `doInBackground` returns `String` value.

Comment: Thanks, i tried that, but i can't get the string back:

class LerHtml extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String response;    

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String...params) {

        try {
            URL externalURL = new URL ... (here comes your code) ... } catch (IOException ex) {

        } return response;

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }



};

Comment: I tried to get it back with "String output = new LerHtml().execute(Params).get();"

Comment: First of all, there is an explanation of AsyncTask generic types:
_Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
Result, the type of the result of the background computation._ Then, you already have wanted string in `onPostExecute(String result)`.